# Performance Bug in Trigger Causing ~1000x Slowdown

Tags: issues, core, performance, bug-reporting

While looking for the root cause of a performance issue for a client, I tracked it down to a couple of triggers performing an inefficient UPDATE statement:

civicrm_activity_before_update
civicrm_activity_before_delete

Original SQL (~4 seconds):

```
UPDATE civicrm_case SET modified_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id IN (SELECT ca.case_id FROM civicrm_case_activity ca WHERE ca.activity_id = OLD.id);
```

~1000x faster SQL to do the same thing:

```
UPDATE civicrm_case, civicrm_case_activity SET civicrm_case.modified_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE civicrm_case.id = civicrm_case_activity.case_id AND civicrm_case_activity.activity_id = OLD.id;
```

I tracked this down to the following PHP file:
sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Container.php

The patch to fix the SQL payload in the file:

```
--- Container.php.orig  2021-04-12 11:30:35.039270421 +0100
+++ Container.php   2021-04-12 11:32:00.485650901 +0100
@@ -286,7 +286,7 @@
             'table' => 'civicrm_activity',
             'when' => 'BEFORE',
             'event' => ['UPDATE', 'DELETE'],
-            'sql' => "\nUPDATE civicrm_case SET modified_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id IN (SELECT ca.case_id FROM civicrm_case_activity ca WHERE ca.activity_id = OLD.id);\n",
+            'sql' => "\nUPDATE civicrm_case, civicrm_case_activity SET civicrm_case.modified_date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE civicrm_case.id = civicrm_case_activity.case_id AND civicrm_case_activity.activity_id = OLD.id;\n",
           ],
         ],
       ]
```

The bug doesn't manifest if you rewrite the UPDATE as a SELECT, but in the UPDATE form it takes an absurdly long time when a sub-select is used. Tested on MariaDB 10.4 and 10.5.

Any thoughts on this? Functionally the two queries are identical. What does it take to get this merged upstream?

Comment: Nice find. To get it merged you need to create a ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/new and then if you're able to also make an associated pull request at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core against master. See also https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/git/#contributing. Then someone needs to confirm and test it.

Comment: Demerit - i suggest you paste above as an answer since the OP question seems to be "What does it take to get this merged upstream?" which you have answered well

Comment: Thanks Petednz-fuzion

Comment: Bug filed here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2576

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice find. Thanks for posting. Yes the inner join is generally better than a subquery.

To answer your secondary question, to get it merged you need to create a ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/new and then if you're able to also make an associated pull request at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core against master. See also https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/git/#contributing. Then someone needs to confirm and test it.

When you do post your ticket, it would help to also describe the parameters (e.g. # of activities in the database, any other relevant variables...) so that others can reproduce/evaluate.